# Why won't MOUSEBUTTONDOWN work in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I an having an error with `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` giving an error when used.

Here is the error:

> ```py
> if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
> NameError: name 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN' is not defined
> ```

Here is the code that is giving the error:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()


# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here



    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    monospace = pygame.font.SysFont("Berlin Sans FB", 169)
    label = monospace.render("test", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 100))

    button_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)  # start button rectangle

    abort = False
    start = False
    while not abort and not start:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                abort = True

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    start = True

        # draw title screen
        # [...]

    done = abort
    while not done:

        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True



    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

All the other sources on Stack Overflow about this topic that I can find all talk about errors where `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` already works.

Also note that I am using Pycharm.

Comment: `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` instead of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: alternatively `from pygame.locals import *`

Comment: You have multiple loops trying to consume events. What if an event you are interested in was available at the top where you check for pygame.QUIT? Any other event will be thrown away.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you it is no longer throwing the error :)

Comment: my problems have now changed to now im just getting a black screen, even after changing font colour to white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` instead of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `from pygame.locals import *`

---

You need only one application loop:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import sys

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
monospace = pygame.font.SysFont("Berlin Sans FB", 169)
label = monospace.render("test", 1, (0, 0, 0))

button_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)  # start button rectangle

abort = False
start = False
while not abort:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            abort = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if not start and button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                start = True

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    if not start:
        # draw title screen
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", button_rect)
    else:
        # draw game 
        # [...]
        screen.blit(label, (100, 100))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

I did not have the needed libraries imported:

For MOUSEBUTTONDOWN to work you need to use:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Credit to @Rabbid76 for answering in comments.